# Numbering Examples using theoremstyle

Tags: examples

I wish to number the examples as Example 2.1 Example 2.2 and so on. But what I end up with is Example 2.1.1 Example 2.2.1 and so on, Following is the syntax I've used. Can anyone suggest some edit to this to remove the third point in example numbers?

```
\theoremstyle{definition}
    \newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

    \begin{exmp}
        WE BEGIN BY TAKING THE EXAMPLE OF....
    \end{exmp}
```

Comment: Wild guess here: change [section] into [chapter] so it starts the number from the chapter (eg 2) instead of the section (eg 2.2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialy posted as a comment but since it was the correct solution, here it is again:

Change `[section]` into `[chapter]` so it starts the number from the chapter (eg 2) instead of the section (eg 2.2).